# Is location:header secure?

Tags: php, security, authentication

While developing a small web app that uses accounts with some admin privileges, I was using location:header when a non-admin account tried to access a page that was for admins. However I was reading that there were some security problems regarding that, but I couldn't get something clear.

Is the redirect using location:header secure? is it enough with this?

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
   header('Location: login'); 
   exit;
}
```

or is there a secure alternative?

Comment: I feel like the security problems you read about involve using user provided data in your redirect. Link to the read?

Comment: Because you're calling `exit` right after the `header` i'd say it's fine, security is more than just calling quits when someone doesn't have a session tho'. Think about how you are storing data, passwords, how you are logging users in, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only more secure alternative would be one that guarantees you don't forget the `exit;` after the `header();` call.

```
<?php
function redirect(string $path)
{
    header("Location: {$path}");
    exit;
}

redirect('/login');
```

Otherwise, congratulations on avoiding a common pitfall with HTTP redirects (i.e. still processing the HTTP request after sending the response header).